# Computing the Transformation Matrix for Basis Change in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a question regarding basis change in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given two bases, e.g., in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $B = (b_1, b_2)$ and $C = (c_1, c_2)$, I want to compute the transformation matrix $P$ for changing from basis $B$ to $C$.

Can I consider $B$ and $C$ (matrices with basis vectors as columns) as transformation matrices for the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$? If so, is it correct to compute $P$ by applying the inverse of $B$ followed by $C$?

For example, given:

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

I calculated $P$ as follows:

Compute $B_{inv} = \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$
Compute $P = CB_{inv} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0.25 & -0.25 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -0.25 & -0.75 \end{bmatrix}$

Is this approach correct? Any insights or advice are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can't be correct. You can pick out a simple case to verify.

For example take $v=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\-2\end{pmatrix}$. $\left[v\right]_B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\left[v\right]_C=\begin{bmatrix} 4\\6\end{bmatrix}$ but your $P_{B \rightarrow C}$ has $P_{B \rightarrow C}\left[v\right]_B \neq \left[v\right]_C$

If you want to find the matrix $P$ which changes from basis $B$ to $C$, the normal approach is to write the basis vectors of $B$ in terms of $C$, and put the coefficients as the columns of $P$:

$b_1=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}=P_{1,1}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+P_{2,1}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\implies P_{1,1}=4, P_{2,1}=6$
$b_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=P_{1,2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+P_{2,2}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\implies P_{1,2}=0, P_{2,2}=-1$

So $P_{B \rightarrow C}=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 6 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $ , and let $ \{\vec{b}_{1},\vec{b}_{2}\} $ and $ \{\vec{c}_{1},\vec{c}_{2}\} $ be two bases of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. We know that a subset of vectors forms a basis of a vector space if and only if each vector can be written uniquely as a linear combination of said basis vectors. Thus we may write $$ \vec{v} = x_{1}\vec{b}_1 + x_{2}\vec{b}_{2} = y_{1}\vec{c}_{1} + y_{2}\vec{c}_2 \text{,}$$ or using matrices, $$ \vec{v} = B\vec{x} = C\vec{y} \text{,}$$ where $ B=\left(\vec{b}_{1}\text{ }\vec{b}_{2}\right)\text{, }C = \left(\vec{c}_{1}\text{ }\vec{c}_{2}\right)\text{, }\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1}\\ x_{2} \end{pmatrix}\text{, } $ and $ \vec{y} = \begin{pmatrix} y_{1}\\y_{2} \end{pmatrix}\text{.} $ 
Suppose $ \vec{x} $ is given. Let's find $ \vec{y} $. $$ B\vec{x}=C\vec{y} $$ $$ C^{-1}B\vec{x}=\vec{y}=P\vec{x} $$ Thus $ P=C^{-1}B $